# How to correctly model UI states with sealed classes in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Say you have a simple screen that displays a list of items. I could define the 3 possible states of the screen like this:

```
 sealed class State() {
        data class Success(val items: List<Item> = listOf()): State()
        object Loading: State()
        data class Error(val error: String? = null): State()
    }
```

In my Compose UI, I treat the states accordingly:

```
when(state) {
    is State.Success -> {
        LazyColumn(...) {...}
    }
    is State.Error -> {
        Text(state.error ?: "")
    }
    is State.Loading -> {
        LoadingBar()
    }
}
```

The first state will be `State.Loading()` as I will initiate a network request to get the items.  When the items arrive, the state becomes `State.Success()`.

But what if, afterwards, the user presses on a button that should trigger another network request?
On top of the existing content, I need to push the `State.Loading` class again to show the loading indicator while the new network request is finished.

Yet this state has no knowledge of the previous items content, so the UI will only show the loading indicator, and it will not render the content from the previous `State.Success()`.

I could fix this by introducing a new State called: `State.LoadingActionWhileSuccess` yet this is not scalable.

**How would you treat such situations? Adding other State classes could work, but it would become un-manageable after some point.**

My biggest worry for this approach is when the screen complexity rises, the combination of possible states gets out of hand.

I could hold the state in a regular `data class` and mutate it, but I found that this approach can introduce illegal states for concurrent mutations.

Comment: I suspect it can help you https://medium.com/geekculture/atomic-updates-with-mutablestateflow-dc0331724405. Shortly, you can use **copy** to change one filed in your state. **_viewState.value = _viewState.value.copy(doneButtonEnabled = true)**. **copy** method need to use together with **MutableStateFlow.update** method

Comment: Mutating a `data class` is prone to illegal states, that's why I was looking for state definition with sealed classes.

Comment: **Mutating a data class is prone to illegal states** Could you provide example? You wrote **I need to push the State.Loading class again to show the loading indicator while the new network request is finished.** You are wrong. You can't understand how compose works a bit

Comment: What does the state value has anything to do with Compose here? And why do your assumptions about my knowledge matter? Your comment makes no sense.

I meant that while the state is currently `State.Success`,  a user  can trigger another network request. The next state should somehow have a loading behavior but yet still display the previous content. The two elements are not mutually exclusive in this case, and I'm trying to find out how to go around this with sealed classes.

Comment: Relax I try to help) There is my example, how it works **Box {
                    if (uiState.loading) {
                        CircularProgressIndicator()
                    }

                    if (!uiState.list.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        LazyColumn {
                        }
                    }
                }** You will see both the indicator and the data that you currently have

Comment: I get your suggestion, this would fix my issue, I agree. I was yet hoping to somehow be able to do that with sealed classes since they prevent illegal states by default.
When using a simple state holder with multiple fields (like in your example) it's easy for multiple concurrent mutation sources to mutate the state into an illegal state.

Comment: I assure you it is easy to maintain. Your approach will lead to the creation of events that should be after some event. For instance -  Instead of a **3-state** class. Will be about **6-state** class. It seems to me. It will confuse faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be difficult to use `sealed class` if the screens aren't mutually exclusive. You could have a `isLoadingNewContent` field outside of the sealed class (or just in `Success`) and call `if(isLoadingNewContent) { LoadingBar() }` before `when(state)`.

I am not sure what you meant by "I could hold the state in a regular data class and mutate it, but I found that this approach can introduce illegal states for concurrent mutations.". Why would there be concurrent mutations? Also, data classes (with `val`) are immutable and `copy` is atomic.

You can have nested data classes to group related data.

```
data class State(
    val data: Data? = null, // null instead of Loading
    val error: String? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false
)

data class Data(
    val items: List<Item>,
    val title: String,
    val count: Int
)

@Composable()
fun Test() = Column {
    val state = State() 

    if(state.isLoading){
        Text("Progress bar")
    }

    if(state.error != null){
        Text(text = state.error)
    } else if (state.data != null) {
        Text(text = state.data.title)
    }
    // everything is null
    else if(!state.isLoading){
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "Load data")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe don't allow the user to start another network call while one is underway by disabling buttons, etc.. Most of the apps I've seen do this. When you do a pull-to-refresh, the refresh icon always shows until the call has ended. This prevents you from making additional calls.

Then again, without knowing your use-case, I'm only making a general suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the success data in your composable with `remember`

```
    var items: List<Item> by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf()) }
```

then in your `when` clause, set the `items`. Do not focus on showing your LazyColumn here.

```
when(state) {
    is State.Success -> {
       items = state.items
    }
    ...
}
```

Outside of this block, just put your LazyColumn into your composable without checking any condition. LazyColumn won't be visible anyway, before you set your items. As long as, you don't clear this `items` data, your list will stay visible when you change your uiState to another "Loading" for instance.

```
LazyColumn(...) {
      items(items.size) {
            val item = item[it]
            YourItem(item) 
      }
}
```

But if you still want to check some condition, you can wrap it with

```
if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
    LazyColumn()
}
else {
    Text("There are no results")
}
```